# Campos do tipo Real no banco com problemas ao carregar Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Há uns 3 ou 4 meses atrás tive esse mesmo problema, que depois de eu remapear toda a minha Model, resolveu. E agora voltou a dar o mesmo problema. Antes era com o **float** e agora com o tipo **Real**. Na minha Model está decimal e dá o erro. Já alterei para **Single, Decimal, decimal, float, double** e continua. Uso Sql Server 2012.

> The 'CustoDiario' property on 'Liberacao' could not be set to a
>   'System.Single' value. You must set this property to a non-null value
>   of type 'System.Decimal'.

A Model

```
[Table("LIBERACAO")]
    public class Liberacao
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Column("ID_LIBERACAO")]
        public int IdLiberacao { get; set; }
        [Column("FLAG_LIBERACAO")]
        public byte FlagLiberacao { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Column("ID_ORCAMENTO")]
        public double IdOrcamento { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_VENDEDOR")]
        public int IdVendedor { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDEDOR")]
        public string Vendedor { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_FILIAL")]
        public int IdFilial { get; set; }
        [Column("FILIAL")]
        public string Filial { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Column("DATALIB")]
        public double DataLib { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Column("HORALIB")]
        public double HoraLib { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_CLIENTE")]
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        [Column("CLIENTE")]
        public string Cliente { get; set; }
        [Column("TIPO_VENDA")]
        public string TipoVenda { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Column("JUROS")]
        public double Juros { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Column("DESCONTO")]
        public double Desconto { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Column("VENCIMENTO")]
        public double Vencimento { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Column("ACRESCIMO")]
        public double Acrescimo { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Column("ENTRADA")]
        public double Entrada { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Column("PRAZO")]
        public double Prazo { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Column("TOTAL_LIQUIDO")]
        public double TotalLiquido { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Column("MIN_TOTAL")]
        public double MinTotal { get; set; }
        [Column("USUARIO")]
        public string Usuario { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Column("CUSTODIARIO")]
        public decimal CustoDiario { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Column("MAX_COMI")]
        public decimal MaxComi { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Column("VALOR_COMI")]
        public decimal ValorComi { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Column("NOVA_COMI")]
        public decimal NovaComi { get; set; }
        [Column("MENSSAGEM")]
        public string Mensagem { get; set; }
        [Column("Menssagem_RET")]
        public string MensagemRet { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Column("DataRetorno")]
        public Single DataRetorno { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Column("HoraRetorno")]
        public Single HoraRetorno { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Column("TempoProcesso")]
        public Single TempoPrecesso { get; set; }
        [Column("Tipo")]
        public int Tipo { get; set; }
        [Column("PROGRAMA")]
        public string Programa { get; set; }
        [Column("NOME_PC")]
        public string NomePc { get; set; }
        [Column("NOME_PROCEDURE")]
        public string NomeProcedure { get; set; }
        [Column("Perc_Juros_Total")]
        public string PercJurosTotal { get; set; }
        [Column("FLAG_CULTURAVENCIDA")]
        public byte FlagCulturaVencida { get; set; }
        [Column("CULTURA")]
        public string Cultura { get; set; }
        [Column("CULTURA_VCTO")]
        public int CulturaVcto { get; set; }
        [Column("FLAG_PRORROGADO")]
        public byte FlagProrrogado { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Column("VALOR_PRORROGADO")]
        public Single ValorProrrogado { get; set; }
        [Column("DIAS_ATRASO")]
        public int DiasAtrazo { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_VENDEDOR2")]
        public int IdVendedor2 { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDEDOR2")]
        public string Vendedor2 { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        [Column("COMISSAO_VEND2")]
        public Single ComissaoVend2 { get; set; }
        [Column("FLAG_COTACAO")]
        public byte FlagCotacao { get; set; }
        [Column("TipoVenda")]
        public string TipoVenda1 { get; set; }
        [Column("Flag_Receber_Atrasado")]
        public byte FlagReceberAtrazado { get; set; }
        [Column("Autorizou_Receber_Atrasado")]
        public string AutorizouReceberAtrazado { get; set; }
```

o método que está no serviço

```
[Route("{id}/{value}")]
        public void AtualizaLiberacao(int id, string value)
        {
            try
            {
                var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
                            .Where(l => l.IdOrcamento == id)
                            .ToList();

                lista.ForEach(f =>
                {
                    f.FlagLiberacao = 1;
                    f.AutorizouReceberAtrazado = value;
                });

                contexto.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

**EDIT1**

Meu contexto

```
public class AutorizadorContext : DbContext
    {
        public AutorizadorContext()
            : base("VLINK")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<AutorizadorContext>(null);
        }
        public DbSet<Liberacao> Liberacoes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ItensLib> ItensLibs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TabelaLiberacao> TabelaLiberacoes { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa alterar o tipo do seu campo CustoDiario de decimal para single, se no banco está como real.
Segue um link abaixo com os tipos de dados no Sql Server e seus equivalentes em C#.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-types-net-framework/mapping-clr-parameter-data

Comment: Oi Carlos, como eu disse no post eu fiz isso. Veja que na minha Model eu pus **Single**. Inclusive na Model eu comentei todos os campos **REAL** e continua dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: Você poderia postar o seu contexto também?

Comment: Quando você altera o tipo de Decimal para Single, continua apresentando o mesmo erro?

Comment: Sim, qualquer configuração o erro persiste. Tive esse problema e foi bem discutido aqui. Aí refiz minha Model, baseado no link passado por você, eu já havia visto ele antes. Estava funcionando, tanto que continua funcionando no site, esse erro está dando aqui em localhost. Testo tudo em localhost e depois subo. No site está rodando. Apenas fui acrescentar outro serviço e nada mais e nem testei o novo serviço. Esse serviço já funcionou. O usuário pediu uma alteração, mas não serviço em si, mas colocar um popup e chamar o serviço de lá. Só alterei o lugar da chamada, mas o serviço continua.

Comment: Tá dando erro agora em quase todos os campos aqui. Tá osso.

Comment: Cara, recomendo você refazer o mapeamento.

Comment: Então, fiz vários clean e recompile e reiniciei o VS algumas vezes e de repente voltou a funcionar. Havia comentado alguns campos e descomentei e continuaram a funcionar. Não sei o que realmente aconteceu, mas se voltar a dar pau, posto novamente. Valeu!!

Comment: Beleza,cara. Se precisar de ajuda estamos as ordens. Abraço.